# jQuery click handlers don't always work in IE 7/8, using v1.5

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-click-event, plupload

I have defined some click event handlers as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  /*
  * Since the "Start Upload" button is available, we don't need to worry about starting the 
  * upload when the user clicks "Update". But we need to make sure to display an error message
  * if there are files in the uploader that have not been uploaded yet.
  */
  $('#myAccount p.buttons input[alt="Update"]').click(function (event) {

    // check if there are files in the uploader
    if (uploader.files.length > 0) {

        // if there are files that have not been uploaded yet, we need to show an error message
        if (uploader.total.uploaded != uploader.files.length) {

            // if the error message hasn't been created yet, create it
            // else, it'll already be visible so we don't need to do anything
            if ($('#upload_error').length == 0) {
                $('<p id="upload_error">Error!</p>').insertAfter('#myAccount p.buttons input[alt="Cancel"]');
            }
            event.preventDefault(); // stop the click event
        }
    }
    // continue click event as normal
  });
});
```

... and ...

```
// if the cancel button is clicked, then remove the files from the uploader
$('#myAccount p.buttons input[alt="Cancel"]').click(function (event) {
    uploader.splice(0, uploader.files.length);
    // continue click event as normal
});
```

Both work fine in Firefox, but in IE8 and IE7 (compatibility mode), these do not work all of the time.

To be a bit more specific, this "uploader" stuff is related to the [Plupload file uploader](http://www.plupload.com/). Essentially, I have this uploader within a form. The form submits fine and the above click handlers work fine if I don't touch the uploader at all.

However, in the following case, the above click handlers don't work: I queue files and let the uploader do its thing, so all files have been uploaded; now I click submit on the form and nothing happens, but I expect the form to submit. Anytime I interact with the uploader, the click event handlers don't work.

I hoping my comments clarify my intentions. Any ideas as to why this isn't working in IE 7/8? What am I doing wrong? Is the `event.preventDefault()` handled differently in IE?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Sorry about that. I am using the newest version, v1.5, but I'm pretty sure this doesn't work using the previous version, v1.4.2

Comment: Tried debugging by using alert("hello")? Those jQuery selections look complex, I would try giving the input an id and trying $("#inputsid").... personally. It could be that in IE it can't find the correct element.

Comment: Yes, I've tried with alerts... putting an alert as the very first line and the very last line always outputs the alert, but the click doesn't seem happen. Also, using the exact ID didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just switched to the Flash runtime. It seems to be working okay for now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`if (event.preventDefault) { event.preventDefault(); } else { event.returnValue = false; }`

test for preventDefault before using it.

That being said, with jQuery you need only `return false;` and it handles everything for you

Comment: What is this doing? If the if-statement evaluates to true, then you do `event.preventDefault()`? What is the logic here?

Comment: Test if event.preventDefault exists before trying to use it.  Not all browsers support it so you need to test it before executing it.  Here is a link to learn more: http://www.openjs.com/articles/prevent_default_action/

Comment: ... but wouldn't `if (event.preventDefault)` execute it automatically if it does exist? Also, if it doesn't exist, wouldn't the event finish all the way through?

Comment: No, it is not executing the function just referencing the object. If it doesn't exist the result will be `null` or `undefined` (both will be interpreted as false) and if it does exist it will return a string that says what the object is (which will be true).

Comment: gotcha... thanks for explaining, but it still doesn't work :/

Comment: This is already being done by jQuery's preventDefault implementation.